# Is it possible to use CASE expressions in a sas oracle pass-through?

Tags: oracle, group-by, sas, case, pass-through

I'm using a SAS-Oracle Pass-Through query with a left join. Is it possible to use a CASE statement in the select?
Here an example:

```
proc sql;
connect to oracle (user=&user. password=&password. buffsize=1000 path=XXX);
create table
lib.test
as select
*
from connection to oracle (
select
 a.variable1
,a.variable2
,a.variable3
,b.variable4
,case when b.variable5 = 'K' and b.variable6 < b.variable7 then b.variable6 else . end as variable_new
from table1 a
left join table2 b
on
a.id=b.id
where 
a.variable5 = 'X'
group by
a.variable1, a.variable2, a.variable2, b.variable4, b.variable_new
);
disconnect from oracle;
quit;
```

Without the codeline with the case statement the code runs without a problem. So I think there has to be changed something.
Is it possible to use a case expression here? Or is there another way to do this?
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you for your help so far! As I mentioned in the comments, I could now run my code by adding the case statement also to the group by.
My new question now is: I have several case statements and therefore create several new columns to my dataset. As I have to include all variables (that are not a sum, count etc.) in the group by statement, I added all the case statements to the group by. But now the lines are doubled, which I don't want.
E.g.

```
select
 a.variable1
,a.variable2
,a.variable3
,b.variable4
,case when b.variable5 = 'K' and b.variable6 < b.variable7 then b.variable6 end as variable_new
,case when b.variable5 = 'K' and b.variable8 >= b.variable9 then b.variable6 end as variable_new_2
from table1 a
left join table2 b
on
a.id=b.id
where 
a.variable5 = 'X'
group by
a.variable1, a.variable2, a.variable2, b.variable4
,case when b.variable5 = 'K' and b.variable6 < b.variable7 then b.variable6 end
,case when b.variable5 = 'K' and b.variable8 >= b.variable9 then b.variable8 end 
);
disconnect from oracle;
```

the result then is of the form

```
 variable1  variable2  variable3 variable4  variable_new  variable_new_2
1                                            variable6    .
1                                               .           variable8
```

instead of just one line like this

```
 variable1  variable2  variable3 variable4  variable_new  variable_new_2
1                                            variable6      variable8
```

How can I group the data like that?

Comment: What is the problem your are encountering ? Error messages? Undesired result set ? Can you provide sample data for A and B, the expected result set and the actual result set ?  Not sure why you code a GROUP BY and have no aggregate functions in the SELECT

Comment: I would like to make sure that there is just one line per ID variable in the result. That's why I'm using a group by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using period to indicate a missing value is SAS syntax.  In Oracle you would probably want to use the keyword NULL instead.

```
,case when b.variable5 = 'K' and b.variable6 < b.variable7 then b.variable6
      else null
 end as variable_new
```

Comment: Moreover, in Oracle (and all other SQL dialects, since the `case` expression is in the SQL Standard) the default value returned by a `case` expression is `null` anyway, so you may leave out the `else` part altogether. Only use it if you want the `case` expression to return something other than `null` in the un-covered "cases".

Comment: @mathquy  That is true, but in general it is always better programming practice to be specific about what you want to happen in all possible cases.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it is possible to use `CASE` in what you're using.

However, it seems that yours is kind of *invalid* (at least, to me).

```
case 
  when b.variable5 = 'K' and b.variable6 < b.variable7 then b.variable6 
  else .               --> here
end as variable_new
```

`else .`? What's that? If you don't know what to do "else", then just

```
case 
  when b.variable5 = 'K' and b.variable6 < b.variable7 then b.variable6 
end as variable_new
```

See if it helps.

---

As of `GROUP BY` issue:

`GROUP BY` is used with aggregations; it has to contain all non-aggregated columns. Your query doesn't aggregate anything at all, so - instead of `GROUP BY`, you could - and should - use **DISTINCT** instead:

```
select DISTINCT        --> DISTINCT here
 a.variable1
,a.variable2
,a.variable3
,b.variable4
,case when ...
from ...
where 
a.variable5 = 'X'
                       --> no GROUP BY here!
```

Comment: Thank you. That's true that the else-condition is not necessayr here. I tried again several versions of the code. If I delete the " group by" it runs. But I would like to put a group by. Are there further suggestions where the problem might be?

Comment: I edited the answer and added some more info. Have a look, please.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I could run my code now succesfully. Instead of using a "." in oracle it was necessary to use "NULL", as @Tom pointed out. And furthermore it was necessary to put the case statement also in the group by statement `from connection to oracle (
select
 a.variable1,...
,case when b.variable5 = 'K' and b.variable6 < b.variable7 then b.variable6 else NULL end as variable_new
from table1 a
left join table2 b
on
a.id=b.id
where 
a.variable5 = 'X'
group by
a.variable1, ...,case when b.variable5 = 'K' and b.variable6 < b.variable7 then b.variable6 else NULL end
);`

Comment: Good Morning, I edited my original question. Anyone there who could help?